# node.js tcp server, client and sent messages like merged

Tags: node.js

I've a node.js (tcp) server, i.e.

```
net.createServer
```

And I've a node.js client. I've created a module.export with a method

```
this.connect = function() {

var client = new net.Socket();

client.setTimeout(5000);

client.connect(settings.collectorport, settings.collectorhost, function() {

    console.log('connected');

});
....
```

And another method, like

```
this.write = function(data, client) {
    client.write(some-string);
}
```

From another node.js file, I invoke such methods from inside a loop like:

```
while (something) {
    agent.write(data,client);
}
```

What happens is that sometimes the server receives, or the client send, two "some-string" all togheter.
I mean, if in the server I log what the server is receiving, I see, sometimes only one "message", sometimes two or three "messages" merged.

What can it be?
Sorry for my lexicon...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of messages you are sending matches the number of messages you are receiving/expecting on the other end, then I think what you're describing is basically how TCP works.

TCP is a stream and so you can't/shouldn't make any assumptions about "message boundaries." You could receive one byte or 10 kilobytes at a time, it just depends on the networking stack and some other factors, so you should be prepared to handle any amount of data that comes in (e.g. create a protocol, perhaps using a delimiter character, to sort out individual "messages").

Comment: And what can I use if I'm sending json messages ?

Comment: A common protocol for JSON is to just using a newline (`\n`) delimiter to separate individual messages. Then on each side you buffer data until you see a newline character. From there it's just a matter of splitting the buffer until there are no more newlines. Any data that's left you set as your buffer (or `''` if no extra data left after a newline).